# data preprocessing in R for removing duplicate in a string

Tags: r, data-quality

I am doing data preprocessing and am stuck at a problem.I have data like **Telma 2525 mg tablet**. I want it to be converted to Telma 25 mg tablet.Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: see `?regex`. Is the format of the string always the same?  `Name ## mg`?

Comment: yes, the format is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gusb()`

```
> x<-rep("Telma 2525 mg tablet",10)
> x
[1] "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet"
[6] "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet" "Telma 2525 mg tablet"

> gsub("Telma 2525 mg tablet","Telma 25 mg tablet",x)

[1] "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet"
[6] "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet" "Telma 25 mg tablet"
```

where `x` is your data source

**EDIT - UPDATED TO MAKE IT GENERIC**

```
d<-data.frame(t=c("blah blah 2525 mg", "blah blah 7272 mg"),stringsAsFactors=F)

remdup<-function(s){
f<-regexec("[0-9]{4}",s)[[1]][1] # find the start point for 4 digits in a row 
sub(substr(s,f,f+1),"",s)        # remove the first match of the first 2 digits
}

lapply(d$t,FUN=function(x)remdup(x))

#[[1]]
#[1] "blah blah 25 mg"
#  
#[[2]]
#[1] "blah blah 72 mg"
```

Comment: I need a general way. ie for telma 1010 mg,telma 7272 mg ,etc

Comment: Updated with a general function

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Replace custom strings with Valid values with Standardization
custom string-Telma 2525 mg
Valid value-Telma 25 mg

Solution 2: through reference table.